# How to Stop HLS.js Video Preloading?

Tags: http-live-streaming, hls.js

I have tried adding the `preload` attribute with a value of `none` to the `video` tag but it doesn’t stop the hls.js Library from preloading from the video.

How can one stop preloading of hls.js videos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to preload the video, do the following:

1. add `autoStartLoad` with a value of `false` when creating the HLS config like this: `new Hls({ autoStartLoad: false })`
2. Add a `play` event listener to the native HTML video element, call `hls.startLoad()`, and then remove that event listener to avoid calling `startLoad` multiple times since it only needs to be called once

For browsers that play hls videos natively, you can just add the `preload` attribute with a value of `false` to the native HTML video element